# use captive portal page on android as normal web page?

Tags: android, google-chrome, captiveportal

I am hosting a web page (from an esp8266 in AP mode) for an rc toy.  I want to easily access the web page from an android cellphone by just selecting the toy in the wifi selection page.  In other words I want to use the captive portal page as a normal web page to run my single-page control app.

Right now the page comes up as connectivitycheck.gstatic.com and the web page has two problems.  One is that I can't figure out how to get rid of a gstatic.com banner at the top of the screen.  The second is that screen gestures like swipe-down for page reload are happening where I've succesfully captured the touch events on a regular page.

I've tried putting up a welcome page that after a delay does a window.open() to a different url.  The second page loads but it stays in the gstatic.com window and nothing has changed.

Does anyone know how I can load a normal web page in the chrome browser from this gstatic.com screen?

Answer (score 1):

I learned this week that you can use DHCP Option 114 to send an URL to navigate to a specific address. As I understand your toy is an AP which gives an IP address to your cellphone, you can check if there is this options are available to your ESP8266. More info you can find here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=q78sq5rv and here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features/captive-portal . Hope that this helps a little.